# Is it possible to use a th with a display flex and a colspan?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I have the following simplified codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzoNNm

Basically, I have this:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="flex" colspan="3">This should stretch</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th>col 2</th>
      <th>col 3</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
</table>
```

The first `th` does not stretch to full width, but instead seems to take the same width as `col 1` in the next row. Why does the first `th` not take full width?

Comment: I assume setting it to display: flex causes the colspan to no longer be applied (because colspan is table cell specific and you're telling it to not act like a table cell). What are you trying to achieve, can you add a flex inside the cell?

Comment: Since `colspan` already _stretch_ the `th` cross the next row of `th`, for what do you need the `display: flex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible, unfortunately. When you change the `display` of any part of the table, you effectively take it away from the table structure (as if it was a `div` element instead of it) and the table layout algorithm starts to use the [anonymous table elements](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) "magic" to fit this element into a broken table structure. In your case, since the `td` is not a table cell anymore, the browser has to wrap it with anonymous table cell, which can't have any non-default styles or attributes, so it behaves as a single non-spanned cell.